# How to put json inner object into another same type of json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object as below.

```
var obj = {
    "_id": "mand-configurations",
    "server-host": "0.0.0.0",
    "server-port": [1890, 1770, 2070],
    "server-rest-api-timeout-in-millis": 3020,
    "server-started": "server started successfuly",
    "stopped-snmp": "server shutdown",
    "connection-failed": "connection to pgw-server failed",
    "request-time-out": "pgw-server request time out",
    "notify-connection-failed-snmp": "connection to notification-server failed",
    "subscription": {
        "control-data": [
            "app",
            "sp"
        ],
        "callback-url": "http://core.sdp:19980/notify",
        "post-notification": true
    },
    "charging-start-time": "01:00",
    "charging-schedulers": [
        {
            "scheduler-name": "fifteen",
            "charging-scheduler-type": "fifteen-days",
            "initial-delay": 10000,
            "batch-execution": 10000,
            "batch-execution-size": 100,
            "charging-schedules": [
                {
                    "charging-model-name": "fixed-fifteen"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and here I get a copy and change the values.

```
var cpyObj = obj;

cpyObj["charging-schedulers"][0]["scheduler-name"] = "some value"
```

then I need to update previous obj with new cpyObj's values. How can I do that thing.

Comment: `var cpyObj = obj;` does not create a copy. It's still the same object. Any changes made to `cpyObj` affect `obj` in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Making any changes in "cpyObj" will change "Obj" too because no copying is performed. So yeah I believe you don't need to do anything.